# Проверка на наличие дробной части

Tags: php

Я получаю число типа `float`. Несмотря на тип, дробная часть есть не всегда.

Как проверить есть ли она?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75613/discussion-on-question-by-dmitryshishkin-----).

Comment: Просто делай интеризацию и все.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию [floor](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.floor.php):

```
$a = 1.5953;
$b = $a - floor($a); // $b = 0.5953

echo ($b ? "Дробная часть есть" : "Дробной части нет");
```

Comment: Да, это работает. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Читайте мой комментарий к вопросу :Р

Comment: @Visman Умничка))

Answer (score 1):

```
if($a - floor($a) != 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Читайте мой комментарий к вопросу :Р

Answer (score 1):

```
$isFraction = ($a != intval($a));
```

Comment: Читайте мой комментарий к вопросу :Р